# Multistore magento in a subfolder

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I am working on a development server and I need to create a Magento (1.9.2) website with 2 different stores inside with different theme, different products and different customers. 
At first I setup my first store, used a theme for it, played with it for a while then decided to add the second store (that would need to be accessed from a different domain when testing is done).
So I followed this tutorial here:
[Magento Multistore Tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/)

I did everything described there using my own configuration but it is not working.
here is what I did:
1. My domain is www.example.com
2. It is hosted on a VHost together with 2 other websites, so my var/www/html folder contains 3 folders:

```
www.example.com 
www.example2.com 
www.example3.com
```

2.I decided to install magento inside the first website, (inside www.example.com)

So I ended up with this structure (for the single store):

```
var/www/html/www.example.com/magento/
```

Now, following the tutorial from the above link:

- I created 2 subfolders inside */magento/*: **firststore** and **secondstore**
- I copied inside each of them the **.htaccess** and **index.php** files from the /magento/ folder
- And then I edited them as explained in the tutorial, with the slight change caused by my folder structure. So, inside .htaccess file I changed the text as follows:

(for the file ../magento/firststore/.htaccess)

```
RewriteBase /magento/firststore/
```

and
(for the file ../magento/secondstore/.htaccess)

```
RewriteBase /magento/secondstore/
```

Then I moved to the index.php files, and:
(in the file ../magento/firststore/.htaccess I made it look like this)

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../includes/config.php';
...
$mageFilename   = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
...
Mage::run('firststore',$mageRunType);
```

Same for the second store, so:

```
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../includes/config.php';
...
$mageFilename   = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
...
Mage::run('secondstore',$mageRunType);
```

In the backend administration I created 2 websites, and each website has a Store and a storeview, so it's like this:

```
Main Website         FirstStore                        FirstStoreView
(Code: firststore)  (Root Category: Default Category)   (Code: default)

secondstore.ro       second store                   SecondStoreview
(Code: secondstore)  (Root Category: Second root) (Code: secondstoreview)
```

Then in System->Configuration->General, with
current configuration scope: First Store  -->> BaseURL: http://www.example.com/magento/firststore/

for Current configuration scope: Second Store  -->> BaseURL: http://www.example.com/magento/secondstore/

Now if I access the url: http://www.example.com/magento/firststore, or http://www.example.com/magento/firststore/index.php
I get an empty page. No error messages, no nothing, just an empty page. Same goes for the secondstore.
What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make it work?